# Possible to Create an ArrayList of Objects in C#/.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, object

I'm trying to create an ArrayList of objects in C#. What I've tried so far is:

```
class POObject
    {
        public List<string> staticCustInfo;
        public List<List<string>> itemCollection;
        public int testInt;
    }

    POObject myObject = new POObject();
    List<POObject> BatchList = new List<POObject>();
```

This is fine, except when I try to add an object to this list using:

```
BatchList.Add(item);
```

It gives me errors saying it can't find a corresponding method to add to the list. Any ideas? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just for clarity, you aren't creating an ArrayList. An ArrayList is a different class from List<>.

Comment: List in .NET is implemented with an array list implementation.

Comment: What's 'item' and why are you adding that and not myObject?

Comment: Fyi, no repro. New c# solution, paste in the class definition for POObject in the Program class above the Main function, paste in these 3 lines into Main: POObject myObject = new POObject(); List<POObject> BatchList = new List<POObject>(); BatchList.Add(myObject); // no compile or runtime errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to store in your list? You declare a BatchList as containing POObjects, but then you're trying to add `item`, which is of what type? If you're adding things to this list that are not POObjects, you can declare it as either a non-generic list:

```
List BatchList = new List();
```

or as a generic list of objects:

```
List<object> BatchList = new List<object>();
```

But I suspect the real problem may be that you're trying to add the wrong type of `item` to your collection. Can you show us how you get your `item` variable?

Comment: Why would this be necessary? Shouldn't a generic List<T> be able to contain his `POObject`?

Comment: @djacobson yes List<T> can store any objects, but you have to first instantiate it with a concrete type parameter - T

Comment: @Max Yes, which the OP is already doing. Now that @StriplingWarrior has extended his answer from just containing that `List<object>` statement, I agree with it - the problem may very well be that `item` is an arbitrary type...

Answer (score 0):

If you declare that BatchList is of type `List<POObject>`, then that means the List can only contain objects of type `POObject`. That's what the type parameter is for. You cannot add strings, ints, or any other arbitrary objects to this list, only POObjects (and descendents of `POObject`).

If you take a look at the intellisense, you will see that Add's signature is this:

```
void Add(POObject item)
```

If you really want a list that contains arbitrary items, then use an `ArrayList`, which is not a generic type and can accept any type of object. However since C# is such a strongly typed language, wanting arbitrary lists like this is usually a code smell.